# Route distance with cloudmade HTTP Request

Tags: php, openstreetmap, cloudmade

Is it possible to get just the distance by making a HTTP Request with cloudemade?

Currently I use this Request:

```
http://routes.cloudmade.com/937c6e7e029348uwb988d8a791156f34/api/0.3/8.18,50.13,10.1,53.281/car.js?lang=de&units=km
```

(More information http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/routing-http-api/examples/find-route)

But this needs a lot of time because the response include the detailes of the route. I just need the distance in meter.

Comment: Where's the problem? Ignore the details and just read the value of _total_distance_.

Comment: I do that exactly. but the problem is the time, cloudmade needs to calculate the route and send the data. To improve the performance I just want to get the data field "total_distance".

Comment: Most of the time is required for the routing itself which you need anyway. If you need very fast routing then you should try [OSRM](http://map.project-osrm.org/) instead. It beats even Google but so far only car routing is supported.